# Using IMPORTXML to just retrieve the closing date and nothing else

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to scrape just the closing date on a website onto google sheets.

currently using `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[@id]")` but it scrapes all the data on the site.

I need just the closing date right at the bottom of this page, is this possible?
https://justicejobs.tal.net/vx/lang-en-GB/mobile-0/appcentre-1/brand-15/xf-5ebef95e1d21/candidate/so/pm/1/pl/3/opp/54025-202202-Prison-Officer-HMP-Leicester/en-GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=IMPORTXML(A1, "//p/span/span/strong/span")
```

or

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1, "//p/span/span/strong/span"),"Closing date (.*)\.")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[@id]")), 
 "where lower(Col1) starts with 'closing date'")
```

[image]

or just a date:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[@id]")),
 "where lower(Col1) starts with 'closing date'"), "(\d+.*).")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much this works perfect! do you know if there would be away of adjusting this to have an or function, I'm trying to apply this to multiple URLs at once and have noticed that on some Closing dats is written either 'Closing date' or 'Closing Date' with a capitalized D, and I think the formula is thrown off by this

Comment: @LuisCarlosDosSantosSousa you can add lower. answer updated. see now